# Ruby and sending emails with Net::SMTP: How do I force a font?

Tags: ruby, email, fonts

I have a ruby app and I am sending emails with this format found in the documentation http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html :

This is a sample code:

```
def send_notification(exception)

    msgstr = <<-END_OF_MESSAGE
  From: Exchange Errors <exchangeerrors@5112.mysite.com>
  To: Edmund Mai <emai@mysite.com>
  Subject: test message
  Date: Sat, 23 Jun 2001 16:26:43 +0900
  Message-Id: <unique.message.id.string@mysite.com>

  This is a test message.
  END_OF_MESSAGE


  Net::SMTP.start('your.smtp.server', 25) do |smtp|
    smtp.send_message msgstr, 'from@address', 'to@address'
  end
end
```

How do I force a font to this email? I want to force it to Courier New.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails allow for basic HTML, and possibly CSS to be used in them.

You should be able to do something like (I'm guessing at the actual font name)

```
<font face="courier new">my text</font>
```

**NOTE**

Not all email readers will parse HTML or CSS. This is not guaranteed to work. Though, it should work in more major email readers.

Also, the `<font></font>` tags are old and should not be used in any other context. They are not supported in HTML5.

Comment: Hi justin, this does not work for gmail. It does not automatically pick up the formatting

Comment: Try using a CSS approach instead.

Comment: I realized i was missing the "Content-type: text/html" tag